# How do I run a function using flags in golang?

Tags: go, flags

I'm making a go tool that pings a url taken from the user, I don't want to follow a strict order of arguments ( e.g os.Args[]  ) so i decided to handle this using flags `./ping -u <the_url> -o <output.txt>`(this is how the tool wanna be used ), but the problem is that i want for example when the "-o" flag is used , i want this function output() to be executed , but not the other ones ?

// Here is my code , I'm still newbie in Golang

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"
)


// this function writes output to a file

func output() {

    file, err := os.OpenFile("output.txt", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666)

    if err != nil {

        fmt.Println("File does not exists or cannot be created")

        os.Exit(1)

    }
    defer file.Close()

    w := bufio.NewWriter(file)
    r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))
    i := r.Perm(5)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v\n", i)

    w.Flush()
}

// this function sends request and returns body in the response

func request_body() {

    url := <url>

    resp2, err := http.Get(url)

    if err != nil {

        log.Fatalln(err)

    } else {

        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp2.Body)

        if err != nil {

            log.Fatalln(err)

        }
        res_body := string(body)

        fmt.Printf(res_body)
    }
}

func main() {

    var target, out string
    flag.StringVar(&target, "t", "", "target to send a request")
    flag.StringVar(&out, "o", "output.txt", "Path to a file to store output")


    flag.Parse()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use default value for the string variable when you do flag. And when you want to use `other function calls`, just check that your flagged variables are empty or not and call.

```
func main() {

    var target, out string
    flag.StringVar(&target, "t", "", "target to send a request")
    flag.StringVar(&out, "o", "output.txt", "Path to a file to store output")
    flag.Parse()

    if target != ``{
        //call your any function using target variable
        fmt.Println(target)
    }
    //call output() when you want anywhere
}
```

when you run code with `-t flag`, it will call the other functions. In my example it will print your parsed flag value.

```
go run main.go -t abc
abc
```

if -t flag not used or not value parse for it, No other function calls. It will print nothin in my example.

```
go run main.go
```

You can use this for every flagged variable. And run your `output()` function call when you want to call it anywhere because you have set default value for `-o` flag.